# How to determine the scope of a function passed as a parameter to a child widget?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, scope, parameter-passing

I'm trying to understand how the function I pass as a parameter to the child widget is able to update the instance attributes of the parent widget.

For example, the below code works:

```
//...some code
DesignedContainer(
  colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
    ? activeCardColor
    : inactiveCardColor,
  cardChild: const GenderWidget(
    genderIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
    genderName: 'MALE',
  ),
  stateReset: () { //Note this function, I will change this below
    setState(() {
    selectedGender = Gender.male;
   });
  },
),
//...some code
class DesignedContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const DesignedContainer({
    this.colour = const Color(0xFF1D1E33),
    this.cardChild,
    this.stateReset,
    super.key,
  });
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Color colour;
  final VoidCallback? stateReset;

  @override
  State<DesignedContainer> createState() => _DesignedContainerState();
}

class _DesignedContainerState extends State<DesignedContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: widget.stateReset, //I shall change this too
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: widget.cardChild,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Whereas if I change the above code so that the setState is moved to the DesignedContainer widget like so:

```
//Inside the parent widget:
stateReset: () => selectedGender = Gender.male,
//some code

//Inside the child widget:
onTap: (){
    setState(() {
        widget.stateReset!();
    });
}
```

I was expecing both versions to work and the latter is not working. I don't understand why.

Comment: In the first version, `DesignedContainer` is inside a stateful widget. When you specify `stateReset: () => setState(...)`, you are capturing a reference to the `setState` of the stateful widget. However, in the second example, you are calling the `setState `of the `DesignedContainer` instead. These are not the same, the first one rebuilds its associated widget, and the second one rebuilds the `DesignedContainer`.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!
Why didn't you add this as an answer?

Comment: It wasn't a very detailed answer, but I've provided you with a better one below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, `DesignedContainer` is inside a stateful widget; let's call it `MyWidget` with an associated `MyWidgetState`. Therefore, when you specify:

```
stateReset: () => setState(...),
```

The `setState` refers to `MyWidgetState.setState`. Why?

*"A closure is a function object that has access to variables in its lexical scope, even when the function is used outside of its original scope. Functions can close over variables defined in surrounding scopes."*

Source: https://dart.dev/language/functions#lexical-closures

The surrounding scope is the `build` method of `MyWidgetState`. In that scope, you have access to the `MyWidgetState.setState` method, which is then captured in the lexical scope of the function you pass to the `stateReset` parameter.

Since that is available because the lexical scope is available *even when the function is used outside of its original scope*, the call correctly calls `MyWidgetState.setState` from your other widget.

---

In the second example, you are calling the `setState` of the `DesignedContainer.setState` instead.

These are not the same, the first one rebuilds its associated widget, and the second one rebuilds the DesignedContainer.

You can reason as to why using the same principles for the first case.